# Where do i make axios/fetch calls in react applications while using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

Im kind of new to the scene of React and Redux so i am a bit confused.

When we want to make a new state (or alter change previous state) we simply do:

```
store.dispatch({type: "LOAD_SOMETHING_SOMEWHERE", payload: /*some value*/})
```

and obviously in our reducer we see which action is called and apply payload to the property of the state object we want to overwrite.

So my question is - where do i make a call to my REST api in this equation?

Do i do it before i dispatch and set the value of payload to be equal to my response?

So it would look something like this:

```
const res = axios.get("https://myendpoint.ep/data")...
store.dispatch({type: "LOAD_SOMETHING_SOMEWHERE", payload: res)
```

Is this a good way of doing things?

I am sorry - I know this is a bad question but im in a hurry with my project and I dont have time for a tutorial or documentation.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You could also read about sagas which are created to handle such side effects

Comment: Ill look into them. Thx

Comment: You can also look into [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) which is a good alternative to `redux-saga`

Comment: You can either something like redux-thunk . This allows you to write an action creator which returns a function instead of an object. This link covers it well https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3

Or you could write some of your own middleware (https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware)  , if your inetrested I'll send you examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action can look something like this:

```
export const getDataAction = () => {

  axios.get("https://myendpoint.ep/data")
  .then(function (response) {
    store.dispatch({type: "API_SUCCESS", payload: response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    store.dispatch({type: "API_ERROR", error);
  });

};
```

Now in your reducer,you can listen to **API_SUCCESS** and **API_ERROR** to get and store the response